# how to access json data in java file

Tags: java, json

i have a json data like this in a string

```
  {
   'MMTStaticCountrySearchResponse':{
      'Country':[
         {
            '-CountryCode':'IN',
            'CitiesCount':'362',
            'CountryName':'India',
            'HotelsCount':'6535'
         },
         {
            '-CountryCode':'SG',
            'CitiesCount':'1',
            'CountryName':'Singapore',
            'HotelsCount':'197'
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

how do i access and store the country name ?

Comment: You'll want a [JSON library](http://json.org), e.g. [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson).

Comment: try jackson , Gson  etc.

Comment: This is not valid JSON. Well, Jackson can still read that, but still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 JSONObject obj = new JSONObject("JsonString");
      Object temp = obj.get("MMTStaticCountrySearchResponse");
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); 
        JSONObject objtemp = new JSONObject(temp.toString());
        JSONArray array = objtemp.getJSONArray("Country");
        for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length() ; i++){
            list.add(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("HotelsCount"));
            System.out.println(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("CountryName"));
            System.out.println(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("HotelsCount"));
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

With Jackson:

```
final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
    .configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_SINGLE_QUOTES, true);

final JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(...);

for (final JsonNode element: node.get("MMTStaticCountrySearchResponse").get("Country")) {
    node.get("CountryName");
    // etc
}
```

Comment: @pramod.nikam.dev Yes, and `JsonNode` implements `Iterable`; for array nodes, it cycles through the array elements